# GraphQL and Python - `No query string was presented` error

Tags: python, graphql

This is what i'm sending over:

```
query = {"query": "mutation { memberCreate ( email:'john.doe@example.com', fullName:'John Doe') { member { id username } } }"}

qb_request = requests.post("some_url",
                  headers={"Accept": "application/json",
                           "Authorization": "some_auth"
                           },
                           data=json.dumps(query))
```

And i get the following error:

```
{u'errors': [{u'message': u'No query string was present'}]}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dumps` transforms the json object into a String and in the headers you're accepting `application/json`. That's incompatible.

Try doing something like:

```
query = {"query": "mutation { memberCreate ( email:'john.doe@example.com', fullName:'John Doe') { member { id username } } }"}

qb_request = requests.post("some_url",
                  headers={
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": "some_auth"
                  },
                  data=query
              )
```